# Telerik Grid disturbed with action column

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-grid

Note: when I added an action column with edit delete image into a Telerik grid, the whole grid is disturbed as shown in screenshot.

This only occurs when I want to add action column.

Any help will be highly apprecieted.

Thank you

[image]

```
<telerik:radgrid id="RadGrid1" runat="server" pagesize="20" width="100%"
            autogeneratecolumns="False">
             <MasterTableView Name="MasterView1" DataKeyNames="Regid" AllowMultiColumnSorting="false">
                     <ItemStyle CssClass="GridRow1" />
                            <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="GridRow2" />  
    <Columns>
      <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Action" DataField="Regid" UniqueName="CkboxDelKey" HeaderStyle-CssClass="LeftGridHeader">
       <ItemTemplate>
                              <nobr>
                                             <asp:ImageButton ID="btnNoteEdit" ToolTip="Edit Goal" ImageUrl="images/EmailAlertEdit.png"
                                                  CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Regid") %>' CommandName="UpdateKeyResult"
                                                runat="server" />
                                            <ItemStyle Width="90px" />

                                            &nbsp;
                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDel" ToolTip="Delete Goal" ImageUrl="images/EmailAlertDelete.png"
                                                CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Regid") %>' CommandName="DelNote" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete?');"
                                                 runat="server" />

                                            <ItemStyle Width="90px" />
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </nobr>
                                       </ItemTemplate>
                                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader"
                                    SortAscImageUrl="images/EmailAlertsGridAsc.png" SortDescImageUrl="images/EmailAlertGridDesc.png"
                                    SortExpression="LastName" UniqueName="LastName">
                                    <ItemStyle Width="90px" />
                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Firstname" HeaderText="Firstname" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader"
                                    SortAscImageUrl="images/EmailAlertsGridAsc.png" SortDescImageUrl="images/EmailAlertGridDesc.png"
                                    SortExpression="Firstname" UniqueName="Firstname">
                                    <ItemStyle Width="90px" />
                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                               <%-- <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="KeyResult" HeaderText="Key Result Score" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader"
                                    SortAscImageUrl="images/EmailAlertsGridAsc.png" SortDescImageUrl="images/EmailAlertGridDesc.png"
                                    SortExpression="KeyResult" UniqueName="KeyResult">
                                    <ItemStyle Width="80px" />
                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>--%>
                                </Columns>
                            </MasterTableView>
         </telerik:radgrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect it to do?  At it's heart, the RadGrid is just a table element with rows and columns.  If you add one more cell to one of the rows, it will not look right.  I suggest making a GridTemplateColumn for every row and deciding whether to show the buttons or not within this cell.